# How to select item from the list of sub menu calling from database using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I call the item list from array into the sub-menu using `createElement("li")`. Now I want to select item from the list. I make them selectable using CSS. But I want to code like when I select an item then I enable to call function for that item. How can i do it?

```js
var gameName = ['Game one', 'Game Two', 'Game three']

function SubMenu() {
  // Set variable for the submenu ul element
  var Submenu = document.getElementById('submenu');
  // For loop - for each value in the array
  for (var i = 0; i < gameName.length; i++) {
    // Create new li/List Item
    var Item = document.createElement('li');
    // Set innerHTML for this element
    Item.innerHTML = '<a href="#">' + gameName[i] + '</a>';
    // Append new element to the submenu.
    Submenu.appendChild(Item);
  }
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Games</a>
  <ul id="submenu"></ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Stake</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Max PLayers</a></li>
<ul>
```

Here 'Game one', 'Game Two', 'Game three' are calling as list of sub menu. Now how I can select 'Game one' so I will able to call a function on it? Thank you.

Comment: Confuses. You want this `['Game one','Game Two','Game three']` will appear on `<ul id="submenu"></ul>` this?

Comment: @Norlihazmey Ghazali they are appearing on it. I am asking that if i select any item from the list on browser then a function must be call by it in backend. So i can select any item so it call a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i make for jquery version since you tagged with jQuery tag :

**HTML**(Assumed items already appeared on `submenu`)

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Games</a>
    <ul id="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Game one</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Game Two</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Game three</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Stake</a>

</li>
<li><a href="#">Max PLayers</a>

</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
// Use event delegation for dynamic content
// this happen when clicked on anchor element(appended element) 
$('#submenu').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).text());
  // updated :
  // find the index of selected element
  alert($(this).parent().index());
   // call any function here
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/Lquzjb44/3/)**

Comment: thank you Sir. it works. but i dont have enough knowledge of jquery. So it is finding the selected hyperlink and alert it. can you tell me how i can find index of selected item. because all items are array items. thank you again

Comment: Put this `alert($(this).parent().index());` to find an index. We find it by `li` element since `anchor` was inside `li`. See updated answer and demo.

Comment: yes thank you. I find the index using same method in different style. but your code are more relevant. hats off

Answer (score 1):

I modified you code slightly, not sure if its work but should this way to be done i think

```js
var gameName=['Game one','Game Two','Game three']
function SubMenu(){
  //Set variable for the submenu ul element
  var Submenu = document.getElementById('submenu');
  //For loop - for each value in the array
  for(var i=0; i<gameName.length; i++){
      //Create new li/List Item
   var Item = document.createElement('li');
      //Set innerHTML for this element
   Item.innerHTML='<a href="#" id=' + gameName[i] + '>'+gameName[i]+'</a>';
      //Append new element to the submenu.
   Submenu.appendChild(Item);
   document.getElementById(gameName[i]).onclick = function(){
      alert('clicked on game name ' + this.id);
    }
  }
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Games</a>
  <ul id="submenu"></ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Stake</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Max PLayers</a></li>
<ul>
```

Comment: thank you for your concern but its not working. having error "Cannot set property 'onclick' of null"